# Do I still need Cloudflare, lossless image compreression, Even if I have wp rocket already?

Tags: cloudflare, cdn

This is my scenario. I am planning to buy cloudflare pro, It has "looseless image compression", feature.

But I have wp rocket already, that does my image compression. My question is what is the difference between the two? Are they not similar?

Thank you and hope someone can enlighten me.

Comment: I don't seen an image compressor on https://wp-rocket.me/features/.